# swift nsTimer to update core data items

Tags: swift, core-data, nstimer

I have a todo list app.
inside this todolist, i have items, each item have due date and frequency.
ex : Item object

- Name : pickup Sarah at the airport
- DueDate : 06/26/16 (26 of june)
- Frequency : weekly

How to reschedule automatically an item ? apps alive, or in background etc ...
in our example : 
After the 26/06/16, this item will be automatically reschedule to 07/03/16 (03 of july)

Should i use NStimer func to call a function to check if an item should be reschedule ? :

Where should i create/initialize this NSTimer (in app delegate and how ? )
Background mode ?

Lot of question on my side ? does anyone have an example of this kind of usage ?

It is not only an NSTimer in an UIViewController.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the web for `nsnotification local scheduled`, one of the sites that comes up is [this](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/), in which he shows you how to do much of what you describe. In particular, his tutorial includes this code:

```
private let ITEMS_KEY = "todoItems"

func addItem(item: TodoItem) { // persist a representation of this todo item in NSUserDefaults
    var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? Dictionary() // if todoItems hasn't been set in user defaults, initialize todoDictionary to an empty dictionary using nil-coalescing operator (??)

    todoDictionary[item.UUID] = ["deadline": item.deadline, "title": item.title, "UUID": item.UUID] // store NSData representation of todo item in dictionary with UUID as key
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoDictionary, forKey: ITEMS_KEY) // save/overwrite todo item list

    // create a corresponding local notification
    var notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Todo Item \"\(item.title)\" Is Overdue" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
    notification.fireDate = item.deadline // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
    notification.userInfo = ["UUID": item.UUID, ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
    notification.category = "TODO_CATEGORY"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

The key concept you're looking for is to use a UILocalNotification and set the fireDate on that.